# CSS custom <li> positioning not working as expected in media query

Tags: html, css

I have created a custom alignment of `li` tags that I want to use in a CSS media query.  Here is a JFiddle how it should look:

https://jsfiddle.net/4fwx7rbj/1/

The `li` are centered in their container and the text is centered with the list images.  Now I tried to use this together with a media query:

https://jsfiddle.net/ro7gj60h/

What should happen is, that the `.half-width` div take `100vw` and the list gets aligned like in the first snippet. However this does not really work as expected, could someone help me what I am missing?

Thanks a lot.

Here the HTML for a quick overview:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="half-width section3">
    <div class="half-width-content">
    <div class="middle-text">
    <h2>A Headline</h2>
    <p>
    Some paragraph
    </p>
      <div class="list-div" id="A">
        <ul class="items-list" id="list">
          <li class="animation-listener">This is a list item</li>
          <li class="animation-listener">This is a list item</li>
          <li class="animation-listener">This is a list item</li>
          <li class="animation-listener">This is a list item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img class="hand-writing-img" src="https://fakeimg.pl/498x50/?text=this is some image">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the display flex in class @media (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 500px)
.list-div {} shrinks the ul

Comment: dont know why theres a downvote, that solved it:D didnt recognized that, thanks a loz